# Unable to login after upgrading to 2.6

Tags: control-panel, ee2-upgrades

I just tried to upgrade to 2.6 - the installation went fine, however now I am unable to login - after logging in, I am always returned to the login screen again.

I know the system has actually logged me in because I can tell from the front end. However I notice the S=0 in the query string so I am guessing it's something to do with the session not being set correctly?

Does anyone have any ideas?  I am using structure 3.3.8 if that is of any help.

Thanks,

Tom

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've just found the culprit and solution for anyone who is having a similar problem.

The problem was being caused by an incompatible version of Zoo Flexible Admin.

1.7.1 has just being released and it

http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/support/zoo-flexible-admin/viewthread/9326

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if it would be helpful or not, but, you could try disabling the session stuff (by using cookies only) via your config.php by using the following:

```
$config['user_session_type'] = 'c';
$config['admin_session_type'] = 'c';
```

Comment: Hi Mick - thanks for that, It does allow me to login - which is awesome. I'd really prefer to use sessions. I did a bit of testing, it could be to do with Structure, If I disable redirect to structure at login, I can actually login, however it's unreliable and I get random logouts after clicking through a few pages of the admin.  Not seeing anything else that could be triggering it - but I have not really delved much into ee modules to know if a third party could be to blame.

Comment: I've just found the culprit and solution for anyone who is having a similar problem.

The problem was being caused by an incompatible version of Zoo Flexible Admin.

1.7.1 has just being released and it solved the issue.

Details in this Devot-ee thread:

http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/support/zoo-flexible-admin/viewthread/9326


Thanks,

Tom

Answer (score 0):

I hit this one also just now with an upgrade from EE 2.5.3 to 2.7.2 - turned out it was Structure causing this in my case - to disable the redirect on login I ran this:

```
UPDATE exp_extensions SET 'enabled'='n' WHERE class='Structure_ext' AND hook='cp_member_login'
```